# QtConcurrent with static member function

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, qtconcurrent

I successfully parallelized some work with non-static member function in QtConcurrent::run(). I am now trying to implement parallelized work with a static member function. I have a Random class, and I want to call rand(double,double) static function on one precise instance: it is a random number generator, and I want to run the thread calling runif on a newly seeded generator. I tried this here (class solveParallel is a simple class where I have a runRandom() and resultRandom() function, calling QtConcurent::run and Qfuture::result() respectively):

```
void solverParallelData::runRandom(const double& d1, const double& d2) 
{
    futureRandom = QtConcurrent::run(Random::rand,this->m_generator, d1, d2);
 }
```

and compilation error is "cannot deduce template argument as function argument is ambiguous": : any clue?

Thanks and regards.

Comment: What is the signature of `Random::rand` ? (If the function is static, trying to call it on a precise instance has no sense).

Comment: Thanks. signature is rand(double,double)

Comment: @alexisdm This makes sense. However, I want to re-seed the random number generator for each thread. How to do that?

Comment: I don't think you can reseed for each thread easily: QtConcurrent uses QThreadPool, and threads from a pool that aren't active for 30 seconds are deleted, so you would "lose the seed" for that thread. And you can't choose on which thread you will call the re-seeding, it would run it on the first available thread from the pool.